# Given $(a_{n+1} - a_n) \rightarrow g$ show $\frac{a_n}{n} \rightarrow g$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

So yea, basically this is the problem. 
$(a_{n+1} - a_n) \rightarrow g$ show $\frac{a_n}{n} \rightarrow g$

It looks like Cauchy's sequence, but I'm not sure. Can we say that if 
$(a_{n+1} - a_n) \rightarrow g$ then $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \rightarrow g$ ? 
So, for large enough $n$ we can say that $$|a_n-g|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ for $\epsilon > 0$. So in this case we have $|a_{n+1}-g| + |a_n-g| <\epsilon$ 
So using triangle's inequality we get 
$$|a_{n+1}-a_n| = |a_{n+1}-g+g-a_n| \leq |a_n-g| + |a_{n+1}-g| < \epsilon$$

So... from that we know that $a_n$ is bounded by $g$.

Is it so far true? If no, how to correct it? If it is true, how to show second part of it? I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: $g$ must be positive? I prefer to do as follows:
Since $(a_{n+1} - a_n) \rightarrow g$ then there exists $N$ such that $g-\epsilon <(a_{n+1} - a_n)<g+\epsilon$ for every $n>N$. Then, for $n$ big enough, we can use telescoping by rewriting $a_n$ as $a_n-a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}-\dots$

Comment: @Jlamprong, g can be a real number.

Comment: if $g<0$ then your claim $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \rightarrow g$ is totally wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Ouch, right, it is very wrong. It think i'm very wrong with the cauchy's sequence, because it states for some large $n$ elements of the sequence are arbitrarily close to each other. So it seems like $a_n \rightarrow \infty$. And the true version is $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\epsilon$, but it's not true from what i have got? 
Edit: maybe if we change $\epsilon$ for $g$ and continue it that will turn out to be true?

Comment: What actually do you want to prove? Do you want to prove if $\{a_n\}$ Cauchy's sequence then $\frac{a_n}n\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: I thought that if i could get factual limit of $a_n$ then i'd be able to show $\frac{a_n}{n} \rightarrow g$

Comment: You're right, but what actually do you prove? I ask it because you mention the Cauchy's sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

> Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}, (b_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be two sequences of real numbers. Assume that $b_n$ is strictly increasing and approaches infinity and the following limit exists:
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\ell.$$ 
>   Then, the limit
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$$ 
>   also exists and it is equal to ℓ.

Now, in your case $b_n=n$.

Comment: That's brilliant! Totaly forgot about Stolz-Cesaro theorem, thank you very much.

Comment: @Chris: It is a very nice theorem. You are very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following fact:

*If $x_n\to x$, then also $\dfrac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}\to x$.*

In our case
$$
\frac{1}{n}\big((a_1-a_0)+(a_3-a_2)+\cdots+(a_n-a_{n-1})\big)=\frac{a_n-a_1}{n}\to g,
$$
but as $\,\dfrac{a_1}{n}\to 0$, then we conclude that $\,\dfrac{a_n}{n}\to g$.

Comment: This is slick but it requires proof of the first claim to make it self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $N_1$ so that $|a_{n+1} - a_n - g| < \epsilon / 2$ whenever $n \geq N_1$. Then choose $N_2$ so that $|a_{N_1}| / n < \epsilon / 2$ whenever $n \geq N_2$. Then for $n \geq \max (N_1, N_2)$ you will have $a_n / n = ((a_n - a_{n-1}) + (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) + \ldots + a_{N_1})/n$ which will be within $\epsilon$ of $(n - N_1)g/n$ which will approach $g$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(n+1)-n}
=\frac g 1 = g.$$